# Want to install Windows 7 on separate drive

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive

I have a two hard drive system with a Vista disk that won't boot, and Ubuntu 10.04 on the other drive. I've tried to restore vista with a bootable repair disk, but I get an error saying drivers are missing. I downloaded drivers from the Gateway site, but none of them appear to work. After spending the last two days trying to restore vista, I'm thinking I might as well install Win 7, after I copy all my personal files from the vista drive. Vista drive is still accessible from the ubuntu side that boots just fine (gotta love linux).

My bios boot order is cd as #1, ubuntu (currently sdb) #2, then vista (currently sda, this disk unable to boot). Grub2 is on sdb #2. AND on sda - I think, that's what the original config was - BestBuy guys did it. But I installed grub2 on sdb yesterday, and changed the boot order.

Will I just be able to pop in the Win7 install disk, and point it to the correct drive, or is it more complicated than that? I'd prefer not to mess with detaching cables inside the machine if I can. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look over there --> under 'Related'. You'll find the answer you seek.

Answer (score 1):

If your primary master disk is the one where you have the NTFS vista partition (hence, where you will install windows 7) you should not have any problem at all, the windows installer won't even notice the other partition on disk 2 since it dont recognizes Ext/2/3/4 partitions.

The only problem I've had so far was once when installing Windows XP on a secondary disk MBR and had linux on the first disk, somehow windows wouldn't boot, but as I said, it was installed on the secondary master, in your case is on the primary master so you shouldnt have any trouble, besides, grub2 is very capable of booting from anywhere, so if you set it up correctly and add the windows 7 installation to grub2 you'll be able to load grub2 from disk 2 and then grub2 will load the MBR of disk 1 which has the windows installation.